# custom ribbon button action on publishing page not taking js custom action

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to create a SharePoint hosted app(for Sp 2013 & 0365) in VS 2013 for adding a ribbon action to site pages, to be shown while editing pages in it.

I am able to populate the button on the edit menu of a page by using the below code:

```
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.RibbonCustomAction1Button"
              Alt="RibbonCustomAction"
              Sequence="100"
              Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
              LabelText="Request RibbonCustomAction1"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
              Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />        
    </CommandUIDefinition>        
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                     CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"/>
    </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension >
```

But the issue is that I am not able to add CommandAction as below:

```
CommandAction="javascript:alert('Test');"
```

and is getting the below error on deployment:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': There
>   were errors when validating the App Package.

And hence the app is not working.
Could you please let me know how to call js here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add anything else but Urls into the CommandAction Property in SharePoint Hosted AddIns (taken from [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins-ux-design-guidelines) -> search for 'CustomAction cannot contain Javascript').

An argumentation why Microsoft designed it this way can be found in this [article](https://sharepointinterface.com/tag/app-model/) (search for 'CommandAction="javascript:LaunchApp').

It seems that the app package is processed on import and certain urls get enhanced to enable the *~appWebUrl* Token.

*Possible duplicate with:*

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759722/sharepoint-o365-custom-ribbon-action*

Comment: thanks for the update @tashunko. the ultimate aim to have an java script action to execute on the button click. so please let me know for any alternative approaches for achieving it. thanks in advance